# I get a memory leak using vector

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, memory-leaks

I've written some simple interface and I want to create a global vector holding objects of a class that implements the interface.
So I did the following:

```
vector<SomeInterface*> ary;
```

I commented out the whole code **apart from**: void main() and vector ary;
and now using _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); in Visual Studio 2010 I get 1 block leaked.

How to fix it?

Regards.

Comment: Where did you dump the memory leaks? Had the vector been destructed when you called it?

Comment: Global objects live beyond the end of `main`, and some leak detectors check for leaks at the end of `main`?

Comment: I dump it right before return 0;. The vector hold nothing, how to destruct it then? (I tried delete ary - not working)

Comment: This could probably use some more details on the code in question. One thing to consider when using pointers to interfaces is that the interface should have a virtual destructor. If it doesn't it's a potential place for a memory leak. http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/123-virtual-destructors-virtual-assignment-and-overriding-virtualization/

Comment: I'm not sure about VS. But if you use valgrind with GCC, valgrind will actually ignore some leaks associated with std containers because they use a special way to handle the memory which looks suspicious to leak detectors.

Comment: `void main`... Change that to standard `int main`. "global vector"... Change that to very non-global vector.

Comment: If you never add anything to a vector, then normally it doesn't need to allocate any storage. However on VS in debug builds I believe that there is an iterator sentinel object which is allocated. This is used so that debug checks can be performed on iterators after the collection has been destroyed. If the vectors destructor hasn't been called yet, this will appear as a leak in the leak checker. It is harmless. Changing your test to ensure that you do not dump leaks until after the globals have been destroyed would help here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to delete the allocated memory.
You have two options:

```
for (auto *p : ary) delete p;
```

or

```
vector<std::unique_ptr<SomeInterface>> ary;
```

The second one is safer, as it will automatically release the memory when you destroy the vector.

Answer (score 1):

The `vector` isn't the cause of your leaks, I can guarantee that much. You are storing `SomeInterface*`s in your vector. I'm assuming you allocate these (`new SomeInterface(...)`) and don't delete them anywhere. I suggest you use smart pointers:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SomeInterface>> ary;
```

If you can't do this, you need to delete your allocations after using them...

```
for(SomeInterface* i : ary)
    delete i;
```